# Graph theory question about distances

Tags: graph-theory

Prove, that for every $n$, a $K(n)$ exists, that no matter how I place $K(n)$ points in the plane, there will always be at least $n$ different distances, that are specified with those points.

My guess is that for $n$, this number is $2n$.

I tried it for lower $n$, and what I got:

If we have $2$ points, no matter how you place them, you get only $1$ kind of distance.

If we have $3$ points, we can place them to be a regular triangle, and in the regular triangle, there is only one kind of distance between two points.

If we have $4$, the worst case scenario is that we have a square, then we have the distance defined by two neighbour vertices, or two oppose vertices(diagonal).

We can use this logic for bigger $n$ too, and I think that I covered the worst case scenario, since $n$ points define the lowest amount of distances, if we make regular polygons.

Answer: For $n$, $K(n) = 2n$.

Is my proving correct? Thanks!

Comment: If you proved, that the worst cases are the regular polygons. I don't think that it is obvious at all.

Comment: That is my problem too, why is it the best. :)

Comment: It is sure, that they aren't the only worst case. Consider the six points of a regular triangle and its middle points.

Comment: This is a problem known as the [Erdos Distinct Distances problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős_distinct_distances_problem).   The $2n$ solution isn't quite right, though it is pretty close:  the actual minimum is on order $n/\log(n)$.